# How to set a discounted price for a Downloadable product type?

Tags: downloadable

Im new to Magento and I'm developing a large scale Mp3 music shop. I created an album with 13 songs(Mp3) as a downloadable product, each Mp3 costs $1 but I want the album to be $10 if the user buys the whole album. How may I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps you: http://www.meabed.net/2013/04/22/promotions-dont-apply-to-downloadable-files-prices-in-magento.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would manage it this way, **without discount or pricing rules**:

- The "Album" itself is a **Configurable** product with 0.00 price
- The "Songs" individually are **Simple** products belonging to that album (the tracks), having an attribute set of "Song" or "Track" and individual pricing of $1.29 or whatever your pricing happens to be
- The "Full Album" is **also a Simple** product belonging to the Configurable, having a **fixed price** of $9.99. The full album product has a different attribute set, the album download file is a zip.

Setting it up this way you now display in your product detail page the separate options *based on attribute sets*. Some simple Javascript will give you functionality like unchecking checkbox types for the songs if you select the full album, for instance. It also allows you to discount one song at a time without having to stack pricing rules.

Comment: Would you approach result in something like this? http://reelpeoplemusic.co.uk/store/products-page/reel-people-music-singles/the-layabouts-feat-portia-monique-bring-me-joy-tell-me-now-directors-cut-ivan-the-terrible-remixes

Comment: For sure. But you'll have to create a new block to load the product list and filter it in the media block. Or get crafty with JS/CSS to reorganize the product details to the left column. Totally doable.

Comment: I get your solution but it has one problem, it uses twice the storage which will be costly.

Comment: A zipped MP3 album can't be so large. I'm curious how you envisioned storing the album in the first place. Downloading every track individually sounds like poor user experience.

Comment: Im planning to sell only MP3 of 320kpbs. I disagree in terms of bad user experience, If you look at big digital stores iTunes,Beatport,Traxsouce etc they allow you to download separately rather than one large file. One of the reason this is important, if you user is buying from a mobile phone, now they have to get an app to extract the file. I'm talking from exp I used to deliver my podcasts in a zip file a lot of mobile users complained.

Comment: Fair enough. Best of luck.

Comment: But thanks for your answer, will look how I can make it work for my requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, if I may ask, why not do the above solution with a download product?

Second Q: Is it possible to make a Simple product a downloadable product? e.g. each song to be represented as a simple product?

Comment: This assumes that it is a configurable product type comprised of downloadable product types, as per your question's title.

Comment: And as it has been a few months I'm curious how you solved it in the end.

Comment: The project was paused, so I had not solved it.

Comment: I'm gonna give your solution a try today :-)

Comment: I have implemented your solution but using a downloadable product type only, you can check it here http://shopscent.co.za/index.php/music/genres/house/deep-house/test-album.html

I have just two questions, how can I disable/hide the checkbox if the song price is 0?