# Create Downloadable Audio product (Album) and sell tracks individually

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable

We want so sell audio files as a Downloadable product. Magento already have a feature that we can achieve this, but it is not yet what we want. **We want to achieve something like [this](http://reelpeoplemusic.co.uk/store/products-page/reel-people-music-singles/the-layabouts-feat-portia-monique-bring-me-joy-tell-me-now-directors-cut-ivan-the-terrible-remixes).**

So, i want to be able to sell the full Album with 12 tracks by $9.99, but i also want to be able to sell each product individually, by $0.99, and list those tracks in the Album product, with samples.

I found this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5989/31366) , but he uses **Simple** products instead of **Downloadable** products. **I need it to be Downloadable**, because i want to use the Magento download system.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First familiarize yourself with Magento's built-in Downloadable product type:

- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-downloadable.html

A general search around Google returns a few existing modules that may fit the requirements you have and could be more turnkey then developing your own. In General Magento doesn't really offer a built-in way to playback audio files via the Web, so an HTML5 player (Flash fallback perhaps?) that could be used on the front end for samples would be one step in the direction of rolling your own solution.  Again, there's lots of open source solutions for this for example: https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

You should be able to set up each song/track as a downloadable product type, then use a grouped/bundled product type for albums.  With this you can then use some Discount rules to allow for different variants of pricing for things like buy 1 track get 50% off the next or such.  And with this approach you can have separate product URLs for SEO purposes for each Song of the album if you like. You can also offer different types of formats such as FLAC or WAV in a zip file of the purchased goods.

Ultimately there's nothing in your example URL that isn't possible with Magento built-in in minus the HTML5 playing of your upload sample audio files.

Some related threads:

- [How to add downloadable product in bundle items magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46326/how-to-add-downloadable-product-in-bundle-items-magento)
- [Is it possible to set Tier Prices on Downloadable products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/is-it-possible-to-set-tier-prices-on-downloadable-products)

Also as a Musician myself, checkout http://platform.cashmusic.org/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, based on [@B00MER](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124571/31366)'s answer we've accomplish our objective, despite some little troubles.

First, [adding downloadable products to bundled/grouped products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46326/how-to-add-downloadable-product-in-bundle-items-magento) was being our main problem, because the downloadable products weren't appearing in the Associated Products list.

Most of the links just tell you to set **'Links can be sold separately' to 'No' for the downloadable product.** After some research we found that **any product attribute set that have any kind of required attribute** can't be added to a bundle/grouped product. What we did:

**1)** Create a *product attribute set* with **no required attributes**.

All downloadable associated products **must** be in this attribute set.

**2)** Create the downloadable products that you want with the attribute set created before. Fill the forms and go to **Downloadable Information.** Here, you **MUST** set *Links can be purchased separately* to **NO**.

**3)** Create a bundle/grouped product **with the attribute set created before** (step 1). (In our case, we created a grouped product). I suggest using the same attribute set that you created before. Then go to **Associated Products** tab and the downloadable products created before should be on the list. I selected 3 downloadable products and set Default Qty to 1.

If you followed these steps until now, you should see a grouped product with the downloadable related products.

Then, we built a little module to apply the audio player and the links to related products to a given category. We managed the full album discount with cart rules, and we can sell each track individually. We also hide the qty box, because the default was set to 1 and Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart is also set to 1.

Our test result is:

[image]

Ps.: https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ isn't responsive, so do consider using another library or create your own.